# Trouble using actions in react-redux presentational component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm new to redux and having trouble wrapping my head around presentational and container components.

**Relevant stack:**

- react v0.14.8
- react-native v0.24.1
- redux v3.5.2
- react-redux v4.4.5

**The issue:**

I have a login button component, which when rendered checks the login status and calls the `onSuccessfulLogin` action which updates the state with the user's Facebook credentials.

However, when trying to separate this into separate presentational/container components, I'm unable to call the onSuccessfulLogin action: `Error: onSuccessfulLogin is not defined`.

What am I doing wrong here? I'd imagine there's something simple that I'm not understanding with the relationship between the two components and the `connect()` function.

**Presentational Component (Login.js)**

```
import React, { PropTypes } from "react-native";
import FBLogin from "react-native-facebook-login";
import UserActions from "../users/UserActions";

class LoginPage extends React.Component {

    render() {

        const { userData, onSuccessfulLogin } = this.props;

        return (
          <FBLogin
              permissions={["email","user_friends"]}
              onLoginFound= { data => {
                  onSuccessfulLogin(data.credentials);
              }}
              />
        )
    }
};

export default LoginPage;
```

**Container Component (LoginContainer.js)**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import LoginPage from "../login/LoginPage";
import UserActions from "../users/UserActions";

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onSuccessfulLogin: (userData) => {
      dispatch(UserActions.userLoggedIn(userData))
    }
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    userData: state.userData
  }
}

const LoginContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(LoginPage);

export default LoginContainer;
```

Also, if I wanted to make the updated `state.userData` accessible to the `LoginPage` component, how would I do that? Any help is appreciated!

**Solved!** When using ES6 classes, you're required to call `super(props)` in a constructor method in order to access the container's properties in the connected presentational component:

```
class LoginPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render(){    
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your container component is supposed to be a **component** and it must have a **render function** with the dumb/presentational components you want to render.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import LoginPage from "../login/LoginPage";
import UserActions from "../users/UserActions";


class LoginContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
          <LoginPage userData={this.props.userData}
              onSuccessfulLogin={this.props.onSuccessfulLogin}
              />
        )
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onSuccessfulLogin: (userData) => {
      dispatch(UserActions.userLoggedIn(userData))
    }
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    userData: state.userData
  }
}


export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(LoginPage);
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused though, because on the redux docs (http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html) they have a container (`containers/VisibleTodoList.js`) that doesn't render anything. What's the difference?

Comment: hm ... that's a basic example where they are using the containers only to inject the state & actions, which is not common, for a more real example check https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world

Comment: Hi QoP, thanks for your replies :) Why wouldn't the code in my example work for just injecting the state and the actions?

Comment: Actually, I figured it out using your example. I wasn't making the properties available to the connected component. I needed to call `super(props)` in the  class constructor. Thanks for your help :)