# Get Redux Store In Presentational Component

Tags: reactjs, redux

This is a tagalong of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37234697/trouble-using-actions-in-react-redux-presentational-component) question here. In contrast to that question, I don't need my presentational component to be a class. Is there a way to retrieve Redux's store without using a class and the corresponding super() method?

**container.js**

```js
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    a: state.a
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    setA: a => dispatch(setA(a)),
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(container);
```

**presentational.js**

```js
function b({ a }) {
  return {
    console.log(a) // returns undefined
  }
}
```

Does the dispatch work the same way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can access the store from anywhere you like. You just need to export it from the file where you create it.

```
import { configureStore } from '...';

export const store = configureStore(...);
```

Import the store in your presentational.js file

```
import {store} from '...'

//  And now you can access the current state or perform a dispatch: 

store.getState() // current state

store.dispatch()
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this, if you are using a react-redux connected component you are in fact doing the exact same thing. You get the state and perform dispatch actions on that state. It's just referencing the state, not altering it.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

**My previous answer was wrong apologies for that**, actually functional components (the one without class) can also access redux state and they can do that using connect from react-redux the very same way class components do

**Reason for previous wrong answer**

I once long ago tried to use `connect` with functional components and it didn't work for some weird reasons but when I converted the functional component to class component it worked without making changes to any other logic so I concluded that only class components can access redux state.
But I was wrong as I tested my case in this sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/38yw3l6nom (*please look out for sample component in containers folder*)

**Previous wrong answer** (*please don't read if you are looking only for the correct solution*)

No, connect from 'react-redux' modules only works on class components. Also, super is a method called in a constructor and hence they can only be called in class. You can refer this link here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes.

If you want any data stored in redux in your presentational component you'll have to pass it through a container component which will have access to the redux store. Please read more about here https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#components.

Comment: Interesting.. so if I want the store to be accessible from any arbitrary presentational component then I will need to use classes? Do I understand correctly?

Comment: yes classes and also you will need to make it a container or a connected component using connect from `react-redux`

Comment: I need to make the presentational component using connect? I thought that went against the whole principle of the presentation component (i.e. a component that just renders and doesn't deal with state)

Comment: so here is the straightforward answer to your question presentational components do not have access to redux-state directly that is why they are presentational they just render according to the information provided them by through props

Comment: I can use `connect` from `react-redux` on functional components as well.

Comment: ^ Use `composition` for that

Comment: Right... so if I am understanding correctly, container components are the only place where connect is used?

Comment: my comments about functional components cannot access redux-state was wrong apologies for that @ChasenBettinger, please ignore those comments. Also corrected my wrong answer with the correct one

Comment: @ChasenBettinger `Container components` is just a nomenclature. For me, everything is a component. Some of them might have `connect` associated with them and some of them doesn't have `connect` associated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `connect` on a presentational component then you'll have to use `composition`. [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose) to achieve that.

```js
import {compose} from 'recompose';

const presentationalComponent = props => {
    return (
        <div>{//Your content here}</div>
    );
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    a: state.a
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    setA: a => dispatch(setA(a)),
  };
}

export default compose(
   connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      mapDispatchToProps
   )
)(presentationalComponent);
```

You'll not have to make `container` component this way.